# PHP Error Message Color

Tags: php, css, html, web

As I mention in the title I am facing a problem to change the error message color to red inside a PHP code, and here is the code:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($r2)>0){

    $msg2="Email already exist";

    echo $msg2;
  }
```

Could anyone help me to modify it ?

All answers are appreciated...

Comment: ... `$msg2 = '<span style="color:red;">Email already exist</span>';` Do find a tutorial on HTML and one for PHP

Comment: This HTML/CSS 101 stuff.

Comment: @Epodax, thanks it works fine. And, thanks for all other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($r2)>0){
    $msg2="Email already exist";
    echo "<font color='red'>" . $msg2 . "</font>;
  }
```

Or CSS:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($r2)>0){
    $msg2="Email already exist";
    echo "<span style='color: red'>" . $msg2 . "</span>;
  }
```

You're being voted down, I think, because this is such a basic simple question that can be easily solved in 10 seconds from Google (others available!). For example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change any color inside PHP, since PHP code stays on the server and colors are seen by the user (which tipically is sitting in front of the client). What you can do is give your message some attribute, tipically a CSS Class, to tell the client to show it in red. I can't see the context of your code only from that snippet, so I'm guessing your function is inside the creation of a page.

In that case I will do something like this:

In the CSS I will put a class called `my_error`:

```
 .my_error{
      color: red;
      /* Other fancy things, to make it look really nice*/
 }
```

Then I will `echo` the message wrapped in something with the `my_error` class. A paragraph should be fine:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($r2)>0){

     $msg2='<p class="my_class">Email already exist</p>';
     echo $msg2;
 }
```

I can think of at least other two ways to do this, depending on where the PHP code is executed, but this is the most simple (and all of them will use at least CSS).